# Proper lua version for tokyo tyrant

Tags: lua

i need to use lua extension in tokyo tyrant server. I have tried all lua versions build from source, everytime llua was found and llua5.1 not, ldd ttserver said that any lua library isnt linked with this binary, so i downloaded binary package from lua website, and ldd gave correct output, but scripting still does not work as it should , in logs i can find only :
ERROR scrextnew failed. everything else works fine, only lua extension wont :(

Comment: The problem could be not in the Lua version that you are using, but in the way you are using it. Please explain how, exactly (commands, relevant config lines, operative system, etc.) are you trying to link both.

Answer (score 0):

In the code there are two spots that produce the error message you see and both are as a result of a failure to this call

```
/* Initialize the global scripting language extension. */
void *scrextnew(void **screxts, int thnum, int thid, const char *path,
                TCADB *adb, TCULOG *ulog, uint32_t sid, TCMDB *stash, TCMDB *lock,
                void (*logger)(int, const char *, void *), void *logopq){
```

This seems to be the loader for the scripting language and there is a path as the 4th parameter - so I'd have a look at some config to see if you need to put a dll/so somewhere, or it's looking in the wrong place? I've never used it (but curious about it now :-)) so just a guess.

[Update]

Had a look in the header - scrext.h and there's some parameter descriptions - there are a number of parameters that need config - path and sid stand out

```
/* Initialize the scripting language extension.
   `screxts' specifies an array of the scripting language extension objects.
   `thnum' specifies the number of the native threads.
   `thid' specifies the thread ID number.
   `path' specifies the path of the initilizing script.
   `adb' specifies the abstract database object.
   `ulog' specifies the update log object.
   `sid' specifies the server ID.
   `stash' specifies the global stash object.
   `lock' specifies the global lock object.
   `logger' specifies the pointer to a function to do with a log message.
   `logopq' specifies the opaque pointer for the logging function.
   The return value is the scripting object or `NULL' on failure. */
void *scrextnew(void **screxts, int thnum, int thid, const char *path,
                TCADB *adb, TCULOG *ulog, uint32_t sid, TCMDB *stash, TCMDB *lock,
                void (*logger)(int, const char *, void *), void *logopq);
```

hth